# Make DropDown Effect panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a panel in a tabcontrol i want to use make effect like panel drop down while user navigates to perticular Tabpage

The Code Below Is I'm using But It's Not Working

```
Private Sub Tabcontrol1_pagechange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tabcontrol1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Panel1.Location = New Point(3, -Panel1.Height)
    Select Case Tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex
        Case 1
            While Panel1.Location.Y < 30
               Panel1.Location = New Point(3, Panel1.Location.Y + 1)
            End While
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a `Timer` to change the location til done.

Comment: `WPF` uses a `StoryBoard` to do effects and is a much cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I Have Seen Examples That it's possible in winforms , see here http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2012/11/quick-drop-down-effect-vbnet.html

Comment: Ok Thanks I have Did it using TImer Thanks . . .

Comment: I didn't say it was not possible in WinForms...

Comment: Please take your time to accept and/or upvote DonA's answer, it seems to be relevant to your end solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Timer` to change the location of the `Panel`. Then when the panel is in place you stop the timer.